# NamedPipeClientStream one time connection

Tags: c#, named-pipes

i have windows service such that it receives data from a TCP connection and then sends same data immediately to a web service through named pipes. can anyone suggest me how i can set the pipe such that i connect one time to the pipe and then use same pipe for all the incoming connection.

This is part of my code on the windows service:

```
    pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipename, PipeDirection.Out);
    while (true)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[100];
            int recv = newTCP.Receive(data, ref tmpRemote);
            try
            {
                pipeStream.Connect(3);
                pipeStream.Write(data,0,recv);
        }
```

Comment: Whh don't you move `pipeStream.Connect(3);` to the place where you create  `NamedPipeClientStream`

Comment: A little more details about the class including the pipe declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Move pipeStream.Connect(3); right before the while(true);
So now you have the stream that you can use over and over for writing.
Now, after every write, if you want the data to go right away, make sure to call the flush method:

```
pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipename, PipeDirection.Out);
pipeStrea.Connect(3);
while(true)
{
    ... // Get your TCP data
    pipeStream.Write(data,0,recv);
    pipeStream.Flush();
```